# How can i merge datauris type: image/png to mpg video file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

if i get let's say 10 png datauris i can convert them to binary but i don't how to go from there, i do know though that in the end it has to be fed to blob object so it becomes a mpg file than it can be either downloaded or played using video player.

The only solution to convert canvas to video so far has been to download or send to server 1000s of png files...which is very impractical. But if it was possible to just manipulate datauri into a blob file that it'd be mpg file.

I'd appreciate if there is a library for this. As i don't want to or think can master files structure.

My goal is to convert animation on canvas to a video file without having to run another script or tricks to convert 10000 png files to mpg ....etc.

so i have....

`"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAABbElEQ…QgmAEMp4UUBDOA4bSQgmAGMJwWUhDMAIbzFrIxpp9xzgVKUgFlH7KerAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="`

`"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAABbElEQ…QgmAEMp4UUBDOA4bSQgmAGMJwWUhDMAIbzFrIxpp9xzgVKUgFlH7KerAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="`

`"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAABbElEQ…QgmAEMp4UUBDOA4bSQgmAGMJwWUhDMAIbzFrIxpp9xzgVKUgFlH7KerAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="`

then i can merge and convert it to this at least somehow...
`"data:video/mpg;base64,iVBORw0KGgoA*******whatever*********AAABw4pVUAAABbElEQ…QgmAEMp4UUBDOA4bSQgmAGMJwWUhDMAIbzFrIxpp9xzgVKUgFlH7KerAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="`

Comment: so is it even possible

Answer (score 0):

you can try whammy js. it takes context, and duration and covert to video.
whammy js link
https://github.com/antimatter15/whammy

Comment: Do you mind sharing some code? the whammy js documentation doesnt say much. Thanks